# How to resolve Maven Plugin connectors issue in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

I am facing issue while importing maven project in eclipse. I have already added maven plugin/software in eclipse. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

1. ejbgen-maven-plugin:1.0.0:ejbgen
2. maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:properties

[image: Issue importing projects in eclipse]

[image: Added following software in eclipse]

Comment: Where is this plugin: `ejbgen-maven-plugin` coming from? Does not exist in central repository... does your build work on plain command line??